# How can I delete in Vim all text from current cursor position to the end of file without using End key?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Is there any other possibility to delete from the current cursor position till end of the file without using the <kbd>End</kbd> keyboard key?

I know that I can perform it with `d<CTRL-End>` but perhaps is there an easier way.

Edit: `dG` doesn't help here as it deletes also the whole line the cursor is currently in. I don't want to delete anything on the left side of the cursor in the current line.

Comment: The dG command does exactly that. d is an operator for deletion, and G is a motion (it takes your cursor to the last line). If you don't want to save the deleted text to a buffer, its "_dG, if you feel you did any of this in error, hit the u key for undo.

Comment: @thinksinbinary dG deletes also the whole line the cursor is currently in. I don't want to delete anything on the left side to the cursor in the current line.

Comment: Yes that is correct, i wasnt thinking about that, but i sure do like the dG command!

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thank you for the feedback - I've correct the title.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With your cursor in starting position to begin, you can do: `vG$d`

- `v` ( enter visual mode )
- `G` ( go to bottom of file )
- `$` ( go to end of line )
- `d` ( delete selection )

Comment: Thank you - it works!

Comment: you can also use the c operator instead of d if you want to add something after where you wanted to delete, it will save you from having to enter insert mode.

Comment: NOTE: `:set nostartofline` makes the `$` redundant, here, and is generally useful anyway.

Comment: @romainl That is incorrect. You still need the `$` to move the cursor to the end of the line, otherwise you end up not deleting part of it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the cursor moves to the same column as it was before the jump.

Comment: @RobBar if this is the best answer to your question, consider accepting it with the V-shaped button to the left. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

#### Remastered original answer

Not the answer you are looking for but (unless we're playing Vim golf) I'd just type `d$jdG` or `DjdG` (as Izkata was kind enough to point out) and nothing fancy. That's deleting the rest of the line with `d$` or `D`, going down one line with `j` and then deleting the rest of the buffer with `dG`.

This is a few more keystrokes but they come naturally to me, my fingers can stay on the home row for the most part and it's done before I even started to think if there's a shorter way to do it.

Anyways it's *much* faster than me playing hide and seek with  <kbd>End</kbd>. Every manufacturer seems to have their own scheme of hiding this fine key. So I would definitely have to look down on my keyboard to locate it. Not worth it.

#### Bonus track

The caveat of above solution is that it's technically *two* deletions. It needs `uu` to undo, can't be repeated with `.` etc.

In comparison, using visual mode as per Zac's great answer we can undo with a single `u` but also not safely repeat. Using visual mode is better in this case but by no means perfect.

Seeing how `d<C-End>` solves exactly the problem and how awkward the <kbd>End</kbd> key is, you may consider remapping the motion to a key you can actually touch type. There does not seem to be a motion `Z` and *z* is at the *end* of the alphabet so I picked it:

```
:onoremap Z <C-End>
```

And `dZ` will behave exactly like `d<C-End>` and remove everything in the buffer starting from the cursor position. The whole family of `cZ`, `yZ` etc. will work.

This, you can undo with `u` and repeat with `.`.

Comment: `d$` can instead be `D`

Comment: @Izkata true. Maybe I'd type `D`... I honestly don't know :-) Definitely preferable from the home row point of view. I seem to like lowercase commands better for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned `DjdG` yet.

- `D` deletes everything from the cursor to the end of the line.
- `j` moves 1 line down
- `dG` deletes all lines till end of file.

It's also fast to type, because all keys are on the home row.

Comment: I'm as surprised as you are.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `d<C-End>` should do as you want.

Your problem with `dG` is that it is linewise (as I think can be gleaned from `:help G`); to force the motion to be character-wise, you could use `v` between the operator and motion. Similarly `V` would force linewise. So `dvG` almost works, but character-wise `G` ends up in column 1.

Fortunately, the `<C-End>` motion goes to the last character on the given line, which defaults to the last line. So it's a bit like `G$` in one motion. Note that this is an "inclusive" motion, so you might want to do `ld<C-End>` if you want to keep the character under the cursor.

Comment: Almost. It does not seem to delete the last line of the buffer.

Comment: @Friedrich Oh, right, because G ends up in column 1. Hm.

Comment: I hate to point it out, but the question was how to do it without pressing the End key. The joke is that OP knew that `<C-End>` does exactly what he wants but he doesn't want to press that exact key.

Comment: @Friedrich oof. By the time we got through with `dvG`, I'd forgotten that. Oh well. I'll let the answer stand… vote away :)